# How to implement Custom Autocomplete Search in Drupal 7 in page.tpl.php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drupal, drupal-7

I am using drupal 7 which i required auto complete custom search function..
where i am using PHP Ajax Search function

```
<div class="frmSearch">
    <input type="text" id="search-box" placeholder="Country Name" />
    <div id="suggesstion-box"></div>
</div>
```

And My Ajax Script is

```
// AJAX call for autocomplete 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search-box").keyup(function(){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "readCountry.php",
        data:'keyword='+$(this).val(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#search-box").css("background","#FFF url(LoaderIcon.gif) no-repeat 165px");
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("#suggesstion-box").show();
            $("#suggesstion-box").html(data);
            $("#search-box").css("background","#FFF");
        }
        });
    });
});
//To select country name
function selectCountry(val) {
$("#search-box").val(val);
$("#suggesstion-box").hide();
}
```

In My database table field name is

```
Country_name
```

I have tried to implement direct php files to search function not working by using above search function...

```
<ul class="">
                <li>
<?php
 print $custom_search_box; 
?>
</li>
                <!-- <li><input type="text" placeholder="Search By Country" class="form-control"></li> -->
                    <?php foreach($dbresult as $row){ ?>
                    <li><a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i><?php echo $row->country_name; ?></a></li>

                    <?php } ?>
                    </ul>
```

This above is I am using to implement Search function..

Any Suggestions how to implement

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some custom table, out of Drupal? My suggestion is not to do that, but to create custom content type system way, so you can use views, module and all other functionality you get from Drupal system and modules.

I that case you could find some autocomplete module out of box:

https://www.drupal.org/project/search_autocomplete

Comment: But i am required for particular table itself not hole website...so trying to write custom queries and ajax..

Comment: How do you mean "whole website"? You can create custom content type, make nodes in that type, query (just) them with views module.